# Get the date one month before and it's always the last day of the month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my db, I have a column, 'Transaction Date' with datetime datatype. For instance, '2011-05-31 00:00:00.000'.
I would like to create a SQL Query by selecting data with whereby the 'Transaction Date' column date is one month before the @InputDate.

I have tried with...
**DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@InputDate)** and it returns **'30-May-2011'**, which is not what i want!
I want the value returns will always be the last day of the month like **'31-May-2011'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last day of same month

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, '2011-05-31'), -1)
```

Last day of last month

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, '2011-05-31'), -1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following scripts:

Last Day of Previous Month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)) LastDay_PreviousMonth
```

Last Day of Current Month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) LastDay_CurrentMonth
```

Last Day of Next Month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0)) LastDay_NextMonth
```

Last Day of Any Month and Year:

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATETIME
SET @dtDate = '8/18/2007'
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0))
LastDay_AnyMonth
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

GETDATE() can be replaced by your input date

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking, given any date, for the last day of the previous month?

If so, the following works (where `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is being used as the date to search from, `'20010101'` and `'20001231'` are constants):

```
select DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'20001231')
```

It works because the relationship between the two constant dates is that, compared to '20010101', '20001231' was the last date of the month before.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2012 you can use the [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) built-in function to get the last day of a month.

So, to get the last day of the previous month you can use this query:

```
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
```

Where instead of `GETDATE()` you can put your Date var.

```
SELECT EOMONTH(@InputDate, -1)
```